# Getting Scrapy to follow specific subdomains and save the .html

Tags: python, scrapy

My problem is fairly simple, but i seem to be blind to see the bug after all these hours I've spent on it. I want to write a simple CrawlSpider that crawls the [edition.cnn.com](http://edition.cnn.com) site and saves the html files. I've noticed that the structure of the site is something like:

> edition.cnn.com/yyyy/mm/dd/any_category/article_name/index.html

This is the code for my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import *

class BrickSetSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'brick_spider'
    start_urls = ['http://edition.cnn.com/']
    max_num = 30

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/2016\/\d\d\/\d\d\/\w*\/.*\/.*'), callback="save_file", follow= True),
    )
    def save_file(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

when i run this with: "scrapy crawl brick_spider" i get only an html file named: .html which i guess should be my starting URL, and nothing else. The spider finishes without any errors. One thing that got my attention though, is this output on the console:

> 2016-12-23 17:09:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://edition.cnn.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
>
> 2016-12-23 17:09:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://edition.cnn.com/> (referer: None) ['cached']

Perhaps there is something wrong with my rule? I've checked it on regexr.com with a sample link from the CNN site and my regular expression is fine.

Any help would be good, thanks is advance

Comment: If you inspect the site with the scrapy shell you can see the main response is mostly empty, it does not contain article links. The content is loaded using  additional requests to separate endpoints, you should scrape those instead.

Comment: @elacuesta would you mind giving me an example of such an endpoint and a way of scraping it?

Comment: Inspect the site using something like chrome dev tools, in the network tab you will find a lot of requests to pages called _zone-manager.html_ (the URL for each of them is different), it seems the site uses those to populate the main page.

Comment: I only get CSS and no HTML results using firebug to inspect it but i've solved it by picking another website to scrap. Thanks for the help !